# Add input search box and fixed table header to html/css/javascript project

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on a sample to accomplish the following:

- Generate an html table of specific data (rows and columns will vary
  in length and information).
- Include a fixed header (the first two rows of the table should be fixed; with the remaining rows to scroll.
- Input box to search all rows for entered letter(s).

Currently I can't get both of these options to work together and after clearing the input box the *Search...* box disappears. It should stay in the same row, right below the header and span all available columns.

My current test code:

```js
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

var header = document.getElementById("myHeader");
var sticky = header.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
    header.classList.add("sticky");
  } else {
    header.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}


$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#myTable tr").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.top-container {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
.header {
  padding: 10px 16px;
  background: #555;
  color: #f1f1f1;
}
.content {
  padding: 16px;
}
.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50;
  width: 100%;
}
.sticky + .content {
  padding-top: 102px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table>
    <table border="1">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Email</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="myTable">
    <tr>
    <td>
      <input id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search..">
    </td>
    </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>john@example.com</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Mary</td>
    <td>Moe</td>
    <td>mary@mail.com</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>July</td>
    <td>Dooley</td>
    <td>july@greatstuff.com</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Anja</td>
    <td>Ravendale</td>
    <td>a_r@test.com</td>
  </tr>
      <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>john@example.com</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Mary</td>
    <td>Moe</td>
    <td>mary@mail.com</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>July</td>
    <td>Dooley</td>
    <td>july@greatstuff.com</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Anja</td>
    <td>Ravendale</td>
    <td>a_r@test.com</td>
  </tr>
      <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>john@example.com</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Mary</td>
    <td>Moe</td>
    <td>mary@mail.com</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>July</td>
    <td>Dooley</td>
    <td>july@greatstuff.com</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Anja</td>
    <td>Ravendale</td>
    <td>a_r@test.com</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I'm more of a vba, sql and C# developer, so this is defiantly outside of my expertise.

I'm not sure how to fix this.

Thanks,
Jeff

Comment: From the code you posted, you don't have an element labeled 'myHeader'

Comment: Also have broken html tags with more than one table declared etc.

Comment: I'm not familiar with html css or javascript, so I'm not sure how I would fix those items you pointed out?